# How to get @IBAction func data into TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm writing a tableview for my search results in iOS.

This is my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var resultArray = NSMutableArray()
@IBOutlet weak var scoreTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var inputText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    scoreTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return resultArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    XXXXXXX
    return cell
}
```

And this is my search and @IBAction func.

```
func search() -> NSMutableArray{
     XXXXXXXXX
     return array
}

@IBAction func btnSearch(_ sender: Any) {
     resultArray = search() 
}
```

However, after building, my table view is blank. In `debugDescription()`, I can see that `func search()` works well and have printed search log.

The `resultArray` in tableview is not the one in @IBAction. It is `empty`.

Comment: As you are a beginner, please don't follow tutorials which suggest `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system. Declare `resultArray` as native Swift `Array` and as specific as possible for example `var resultArray = [String}()`

Comment: PS: Does the `search()` function run an asynchronous task? If yes you can't use a return value.

Comment: The tableViews behavior is correct. According to your code the results array is always empty, and your only reloading the tableView in the viewWillAppear which is not necessary. Please provide the code on the search method to assist you better

Comment: Thanks for your generous advice. I finally found that I forgot assign DataSource and Delegate to tableView. It's embarrassing.......

Comment: I use NSMutableArray because the data is very complicated. I just built a model for this array. {class scoreModel: NSObject {XXXXXX}.Whatever, THANK YOU GUYS FOR HELPING ME. YOU ARE SO NICE! (English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload data again after changing resultArray.

```
@IBAction func btnSearch(_ sender: Any) {
  resultArray = search() 
  scoreTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: reload data didn't work. And sadly, the resultArray in func search() didn't changing either when I input another inputText. It just showed the first one in the debugDescription().

Comment: Use breakpoint on function btnSearch to find out whether this method is being called. If not, try to hook it up to your button again.

Comment: Thanks for your generous advice.  I fixed by adding assignment of DataSource and Delegate to tableView. It's embarrassing.......

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just forgot to assign DataSource and Delegate to tableView. I built tableview manually from storyboard.

And I misunderstood that there's need to assign DataSource and Delegate, if I did it in storyboard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scoreTableView.dataSource = self
    scoreTableView.delegate = self
```